# How to use Ivy + IvyDE in eclipse to put different jars in lib and web-inf/lib

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy, ivyde

So, I'm trying to add Ivy to my project, which outputs a WAR file.  Some dependencies, like RESTEasy and Jackson are available at runtime in JBoss, so I don't want those in my war/WEB-INF/lib folder.  Others libraries are not available via JBoss modules, so I want to include those in my project.

** NOTE: In eclipse, I'm using the Dynamic Web Module facet.  The idea is to get IvyDE to copy the desired runtime dependencies into war/WEB-INF/lib.

Initially I created 2 ivy configuration files:

- ivy.xml - runtime (not included in WAR)
- ivy_web.xml - include in war

Then I used the GUI to configure the IDE equivalent of the Ant retrieve task.  So, in my ANT build file, which I don't really want to use in my IDE, I have the following:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="war/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" file="ivy-web.xml" type="jar" />
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" file="ivy.xml" type="jar" />
```

- image not allowed yet :-(

I noticed in another post comment ([mapping multiple ivy files in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956393/mapping-multiple-ivy-files-in-eclipse#comment17578537_12956393)) they mention using only 1 ivy.xml - but I'm not quite sure how to get there?

Oh, I also noticed this as well:  [IvyDE + WTP: How to workaround that ivy library is ignored by WTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955826/ivyde-wtp-how-to-workaround-that-ivy-library-is-ignored-by-wtp) - however my project doesn't use the right kind of facets, and I'd rather not add them.

So, after reading this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575318/880884) post, I added compile and runtime configurations to my project.  It looks about like this:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="used for building"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="used for running"/>
</configurations>

 <dependencies>
    <!-- compile -->
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-core-asl" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-xc" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-jaxrs" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>


    <!-- runtime -->
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="14.0.1" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0"  conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="aopalliance" name="aopalliance" rev="1.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="1" conf="runtime->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

Again, I tried to add just the one ivy.xml.  Next I went the Project properties > Ivy > Retrieve List >  Add - Added 2 different configurations, one for compile, which maps to /lib.  The other uses the 'runtime' configuration and specifies "war/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" for the retrieve pattern.

However, I end up with the "compile" in my war/WEB-INF/lib/, which is NOT what I wanted. I ONLY want the runtime dependencies copied there.

Answer (score 3):

I think the bit you're missing is the use of configurations, in the retrieve task:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="compile" />
```

Configurations are ivy's mechanism to group dependencies together.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── target
    ├── lib
    │   ├── jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
    │   ├── jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
    │   ├── jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
    │   └── jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
    ├── reports
    │   ├── ivy-report.css
    │   ├── myorg-mymodule-compile.html
    │   └── myorg-mymodule-runtime.html
    └── war
        └── WEB-INF
            └── lib
                ├── aopalliance-1.0.jar
                ├── asm-3.1.jar
                ├── cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
                ├── guava-14.0.1.jar
                ├── guice-3.0.jar
                └── javax.inject-1.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="retrieve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

   <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

    <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve dependencies">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>
    </target>

    <target name="retrieve" depends="resolve" description="Populate directories">
      <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="compile" />
      <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="runtime" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The example above also generates a dependency resolution report, which I find very useful for seeing the content of each configuration.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="mymodule"/>

  <configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="used for building"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="used for running"/>
  </configurations>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- compile -->
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-core-asl" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-xc" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-jaxrs" rev="1.9.2" conf="compile->default"/>

    <!-- runtime -->
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="14.0.1" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="aopalliance" name="aopalliance" rev="1.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="1" conf="runtime->default"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: I was happy that I found this question, because it's the exact question I have. Unfortunately, I don't understand the answer. It doesn't seem like it is answering the question. The OP and I are using the IvyDE plugin.

Comment: @stepanian I use ivy with ANT, so have supplied an example build.xml example. The Eclipse plugin should work just fine. Have you tried the example?

Comment: So once the "compile" and "runtime" configurations are defined in the ivy.xml file (which I understand) how do you make ivyDE not add the "compile" dependencies to the Eclipse generated war file? I don't want to mess with the build files - that's one of the nice things about using the plugin I thought.

Comment: @stepanian Sorry, I don't really understand the issue. Isn't it the ANT build file creating the WAR?

Comment: It's really my problem - I never use the build files directly. I use the Eclipse export to war tool to create the war file. Currently all the dependencies from the ivy.XML file get added to the war. I want to exclude some. I need the simplest way to accomplish this. I will post a separate question and link to it here in a comment.

Comment: Here is the question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207995/exclude-ivy-dependencies-in-war-file

Comment: @stepanian Now I understand and you are best publishing this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this today.  Given the IvyDE component, we're still missing a bit of relevant information here.  In order to make things work the way I wanted fully inside the Eclipse IDE, I leveraged some less than obvious features in IvyDE.

## 1 - For the Ivy library in the project, edit the settings to only include the 'provided' properties.  Expand the Java libraries tree, then right-click on "Ivy", choose "properties".

[image: IvyDE Managed Libraries]

## 2 - For the WEB-INF/lib libraries, leverage the retrieve capability under the Project properties, IvyDE section.

[image]

Choose the appropriate configuration(s) and set the Pattern to the location of you WEB-INF/lib folder.

[image]

Comment: Note: there is apparently a new-ish feature in IvyDE that is more directly intended to address the WEB-INF/lib need, and works with WTP.  I've yet to try it out though.